# How to activate retail Windows 8.1 installation with volume product key

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

I own a ASUS Zenbook UX31A preinstalled with Windows 8 and upgraded by me to Windows 8.1.
The product key is a volume product key.
I'm cannot reset of refresh the installation because the recovery partition is locked, therefore I need to install Windows from scratch and not from the recovery wizard (F9).

I can install a legit Windows 8.1 retail on my Zenbook (with a retail key), but I want to activate it later on with my volume key.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, tis is possible. Simply use `slmgr.vbs -ipk <VLKey>` to install the key. If this is a MAK Key, activate Windows via `slmgr.vbs -ato`. If it is a KMS key, you need to point to the KMS server first with `slmgr.vbs –skms KMSServerNameorIP` before activating the Windows.